# can i use a generic app id for multiple websites' like boxes

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I am going insane with this. It used to just work! I'm a programmer but not up to date with all this modern languages stuff and have no desire to learn it - too darn old, just want an easy life.

Okay, so here's the thing... I used to have these "like boxes" on my websites. Then they stopped working. I looked in the dev docs and fixed the absolute URL and they worked ok on IE browsers but not on Chrome.

It looks like I need an App Id.

So I created an App Id on a test website - I have no idea what it is or why I need one. All I want to do is show on the website it has n likes and the button for Facebook lovers to like it too.

But do I need to create an App Id for every single clients website? How do other CMS systems handle it? My sites are not html 5 - I'd be happy with just an iframe solution.

I'm not a fan of Facebook at all, and this is driving me further away. I'm willing to be dragged back but all I see is lots of overly complex code to achieve nothing really useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do whatever you want with your app ID, but if you use the same one for all your sites, you won't be able to separate those in your "Insights"

https://www.facebook.com/insights/

Comment: I'm adding an appid to the likebox code but it just reports an error saying "Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains."


I just don't get this whole app thing if I'm honest. An app to me is a weather app on my mobile and I'm really struggling to get a handle on why, yet alone what.

As it stands it appears every one of my clients will have to create an "app" in order to get an id?

Comment: An application is a logical grouping of functionality presented to the user. It does not need to have a hard boundary. However, one of Facebook's enforced definitions is that an app lives within a single domain name, and that's what the error is warning you about. If you manage two web sites 1.com and 2.com, you will need at least two APP IDs, one for each domain name.